# constructor-arg ref from properties in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have  bean which has to be binded at run time.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="${requiredBean:mysql}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mysql" class="xxx.xxx.xxxxxx">
</bean>

<bean id="mongo" class="xxx.xxx.xxxxxx">
</bean>
```

In the property file I added the  property

```
requiredBean=mongo
```

But due to some reason the requiredBean from the properties file is not picked up by the spring (The properties file is configured correctly and all other properties are loading properly except for this one).

I just want to know if the syntax that I used for declaring the arg for constructor aa ref is right or is there any other way to declare it.

Pls help me to resolve this.

Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Not enough information. Post the path of the property file that is getting read and the one that is not getting read.

Comment: The properties file is getting read fine. All the other properties in the property file are getting reflected except for this one property

Comment: What is `xxx.xxx.xxxxxx` in `<bean id="mysql" class="xxx.xxx.xxxxxx">`

Comment: It is some class that I am pointing to initialize the bean. I just want to know if there is some thing wrong with the way that I am passing the reference to the constructor is correct or not.

Comment: That's because you're not using the name given in the properties file. Use the same name as specified in the properties file. `<constructor-arg ref="${requiredBean}"/>` as `requiredBean` is the name of the property in the properties file.

Comment: But why is it not overriding it with the value in the properties file?I did the same with the property and it was working fine but with the constructor it is not... can you pls eloborate  a little if possible

Comment: @R.J I tried the way that you have suggested but it is throwing an exception as "Could not resolve placeholder 'entity.dataSource'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure (as you already mentioned in the content of .properties) that you are mentioning the right property(no spelling error), then problem is something else, and not the property itself. Try removing the default value . It must throw exception like   ::::                           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'XYZ' in string value "${XYZ}".  If it does not throw this exception, issue is not related to this bean at all.

Comment: I removed the default value and it is throwing the exception "Could not resolve placeholder 'requiredBean' ". But I am reading all my properties form the same file so is there anything that I need to change.

Comment: May i ask you to change the property name (just for test purpose) say myprop in both places and try again?  myprop=mongo and <constructor-arg ref="${myprop}"/>.   I am wondering if this requiredBean is a keyword.

Comment: Hi Thanks , that sure worked for me ..actually I was using the "entity.datasource" which might be some keyword that resolved it forme

Comment: if you got the answer, please feel free to accept the correct one.